# The package linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: package-management, dpkg, linux-headers

The error message in the notification was:

```
Unknown error:'<class'Systemerror'>'E:The package linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

**When i tried this command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic`it shows  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

When i tried

```
sudo apt-get update  
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease  
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease  
Hit:3 (It shows a link of download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease)  
Reading package lists... Done
```

I think sudo apt-get update command works fine here.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic` in a terminal window.  In case you need further help, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/959990/edit) the question, copy/paste, and add the output of that command.

Comment: When i tried this command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic` it shows_ Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it._

Comment: So, what's the output of `sudo apt-get update`? As said above, edit the question, and copy/paste the output there. Comments are not for that.

Comment: You need to regenerate the default repository list, because, while `apt-get update` runs without errors, all of the standard Ubuntu repositories are missing (main, universe, restricted, multiverse). Check this question for guidance: https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories.